# Accessing variables from a discord cog

Tags: discord.py

I want to know if there is away I can access any of the variables `num` and `char` from the cog file without having to import them into the main file

Thank for you the help in advance!.

Main file:

```
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name)
```

The cog file:

```
num=123
class Commands:
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot=bot

    char='abc'

def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(Commands(bot))
```

Comment: All of your code that relies on the cog should be in the cog.  What exactly are you planning to do with those values in your main bot?

Comment: I want to put event functions in the main file separate from the cog file, I'm trying to save the bot settings that the users used. Like for example a welcome message when new users join a server.